# IE won't display ul on hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer, colors

I can't get the ul li ul to display in IE. On hover the border of the ul li ul li appears but you cannot see the background or links.  When I move the mouse over it, it disappears. Works in all other browsers. Everything I read said to add a background-color to the li but that didn't do it.  I've tried everything I can think of, I'm stuck!
Here's the CSS

```
ul.menuDiv { 
    width:998px; 
    height:60px; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    z-index:0; 
    list-style:none;
}
ul.menuDiv li.menuItem { 
    position:relative; 
    width: 141px; 
    height:36px; 
    display:block; 
    float:left; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #960; 
    border-top: 1px solid #960; 
    border-right:1px solid #000; 
    text-align:center; 
    padding-top: 22px; 
    z-index:1; 
}
ul.menuDiv li.menuItem:hover {
    background-color: #D39400;
    cursor:pointer; 
    border-top: 2px inset #000; 
    padding-top: 21px;
}
ul.menuDiv ul.menuSubItemHolder { 
    display:none; background-color:#F9B300;
}
ul.menuDiv li.parent:hover ul.menuSubItemHolder {  
    list-style:none; 
    display:block; 
    visibility:visible; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:57px; 
    left:-1px; 
    width: 200px; 
    background-color:#D39400; 
    z-index:2 
}
ul.menuDiv ul li.menuSubItem { 
    position:relative; 
    display:block; 
    width: 195px; 
    height:30px; 
    background-color:#F9B300; 
    border:1px solid #000; 
    border-top:none; 
    padding: 12px 0 0 5px; 
    text-align:left; z-index:3
}
```

and here's the HTML

```
<div class="menuBar shadowBottom">
    <ul class="menuDiv">
        <li class="menuItem first"><a class="mainA" href="site.com">Welcome</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem parent"><a class="mainA" href="site.com"><span>BATH ARMOR&trade;</span></a>
            <ul class="menuSubItemHolder shadow">
                <li class="menuSubItem"><a class="subA" href="site.com">Tub and Shower Liners</a></li>
                <li class="menuSubItem"><a class="subA" href="site.com">Colors and Patterns</a></li>
                <li class="menuSubItem"><a class="subA" href="site.com">Accessories and Features</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Found the problem.** the filter below in css was causing the issue.
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#F9B300, endColorstr=#8E6800);

Comment: which version? works for me on 9 EDIT: works on 7,8 as well

Comment: Which version of IE are you having trouble with? It works okay here in IE9.

Comment: on ie9 the borders of the ul li ul li show.  on ie 7 and 8 nothing shows

Comment: I just tested with just the code I posted and it did work, appears to be something else affecting it.  i will have to start adding piece by piece until I find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to specify doctype depending on the version of IE, so it doesn't go into quirks mode producing the error you are getting.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I've actually tried multiple doctypes with no luck, thanks though.